# How to debug onDestroy(), Android system kills app while paused in debugger

Tags: android, debugging

I have a bug I'm trying to analyze that occurs when the Activity's onDestroy() method is called after hitting the back button.  I've put breakpoints in the offending code (using Eclipse).  The debugger pauses the app at the breakpoint, but the Android system also takes the app off the screen and returns to the phone's homescreen.  After the app is paused for about 10 seconds, the app's thread seems to get destroyed by the Android system because the debugger suddenly disconnects.

Any ideas on how to keep the Android system from doing this?  I need to keep the app alive so I can step in the debugger, look at variables, etc.

Phone is running Android 2.3.5.

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for, but android.util.Log

Comment: If you're doing enough work in onDestroy that you need a debugger, that's already a problem.

Comment: Have you overridden the `OnDestroy()` method? if not, do so, and put a debug pause there, and make sure it is before `super.OnDestroy()`

Comment: On most mobile frameworks system will kill the app after some time whether it finished cleanup or not. I doubt you can disable it on stock system. Just use Log and logcat as it was suggested.

Comment: @GabeSechan and CodeShane, this is unhelpful, judgmental advice.  The crash is happening in a local service that is being destroyed because the Activity in unbinding from it.

Comment: @DrakeClarris, thanks for the idea. Unfortunately doesn't fix the problem.  The system still kills the app while its paused in the debugger in onDestroy(), before super.onDestroy() is called.

Comment: @jfritz42, sorry, not trying to sound judgemental. In my experience Android stops playing nicely with the debugger once onDestroy() is called. I'll poke around some for a better answer.

Comment: I may have found a solution.  I put a startActivity() call into onDestroy() (before super.onDestroy()) that starts a dummy instance of the Activity, just to keep the app alive.  The debugger connection is still alive after 5 minutes.

Comment: Oops, no, I take that back.  It disconnected the first app and started another one.  Anyway, I'll just throw some log statements into the code and go that route.

Comment: No, its the best help.  onDestroy is not supposed to do anything resource intensive.  If its doing more than freeing up resources, your architecture is wrong.  And if you need a debugger to solve a null pointer problem where you have a line number of the crash, you need to work on your debugging skills.  Debuggers are for complex problems with lots of moving pieces, if you turn to it for every problem you'll never learn how to think critically or debug complex problems.  Not to mention that just adding 3 or 4 log statements is an order of magnitude faster than coming here.

Comment: @GabeSechan, I post things on Stackoverflow partly so other people facing the same problem will find a solution. Also, has it occurred to you that this is a bug, not an architectural decision, that so much is happening in onDestroy(). The bug was that a closed network connection triggered Observers to fire, triggering other code in the app the run. Just had to unregister the Observers in onPause().

Comment: To everybody else, my fix of calling startActivity() in onDestroy() does seem to work. The trick is that when the phone pops up a dialog saying the app is not responding (Force Close or Wait), don't click Wait, just leave it alone.

Comment: @jfritz42, glad you found your problem! :) Personally, I like to start & stop network connections in onResume and onPause since they are guaranteed to be called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A workaround that I found is to put a `startActivity()` call into `onDestroy()` (before `super.onDestroy()`) that starts a dummy instance of the Activity, just to keep the app alive.  The Android system won't garbage collect the app thread because there is still an Activity running within it (the new dummy Activity).  This in turn allows you to debug things because the debugger's connection to thread won't be lost.

If the phone pops up a dialog saying the app is not responding (Force Close or Wait), don't click Wait, just leave it alone.  It seemed that clicking Wait caused the app thread to be killed and a new thread was created for the dummy Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a breakpoint on `super.onDestroy()`, but I suspect you'll have the same luck. :(

Android won't let you linger in `onDestroy`, it will timeout, so try to accomplish your shutdown more quickly. `onDestroy()` is intended only for freeing resources and isn't always called before termination; data should be persisted in `onPause()` or `onStop()`.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

Addendum: Other options include using a background service for some of the work or to manually handle the back button to give yourself more time, but it could negatively impact user experience.

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193a/03/

*sent from my phone, please cut my thumbs some slack.*

Comment: does not really answer what was asked. He asked how he could extend the time to debug...

Comment: The debugger is attempting to pause the app in onDestroy, but afaik Android will simply stop the process. Moving everything from onDestroy to onPause is a bit of a hack, but should work reliably.