# Android check if application is paused on debugger

Tags: android

I am debugging Android application freezes detection (ANRs) that basically runs a logic when one of thread doesn't respond. (Something similar to https://github.com/SalomonBrys/ANR-WatchDog)

My logic is executed also when a developer sets a breakpoint and a thread is stopped by a break-point - which is accurate from the logical point of view.

Nonetheless, I would like to detect whether a thread is stopped by either debugger or an error in logic (i.e. deadlock) and exclude first case from being detected (as false-positive).

Very naive logic that could prevent this is to wrap my detection by `Debug.isDebuggerConnected()`, but this basically disables ANR detection when application is connected to debugger.

Is there any way to detect if a thread has been stopped intentionally by a developer setting a break point?

Answer (score 0):

Check any of these

[How to debug onDestroy(), Android system kills app while paused in debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979385/how-to-debug-ondestroy-android-system-kills-app-while-paused-in-debugger)

https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/user-interface-basics-637d41b1-35dc-400a-bcc3-65794760474d/debugging-breakpoints-and-the-android-debugger

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've got familiar with links what you sent me, although they touch interesting topics they don't apply on my case, as I'm looking for fully programmatic solution.