# Is there a way to delete anonymous user from Firebase Database Authentication and Firebase Database UID?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

**What currently happens:** when user logs out as an anonymous user using `onBackPressed` and `case R.id.logoutMenuOption` , their Firebase Auth and Firebase Database Uid gets removed correctly.  Except, when a user swipe closes the app the `onDestroy()` method is called but their Firebase Auth and Firebase Database Uid still remains in the Database.  I use the `onDestroy()` when the user swipe closes the app.

**What I need to happen:** when a user swipe closes the app, the `onDestroy()` and `removeAnonymousVendorUser()` methods are called to delete the anonymous users authentication as well as their User Uid from the Realtime Database.

**What I have done so far:** I have created the `removeAnonymousVendorUser()` method and placed it in the `onDestroy()` method.  I also will show how it is used in my other logout methods, and in those methods it does work, it just does not work for the `onDestroy()`

```
  @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //TODO: Figure out how to delete UID and user when they sign out
    removeAnonymousVendorUser();
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    finish();
}
```

**Method that removes the anonymous user Firebase Auth data and Firebase Database data:**

```
  private void removeAnonymousVendorUser() {

    if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        user.delete();
    }

    DatabaseReference vendorIdReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Vendor");
    vendorIdReference.removeValue();

}
```

**Logout Method when user clicks Logout menu option button:**

```
           //Logout Menu Option Button
              @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

             // If Logout Button is clicked within 2 Seconds log user out
            case R.id.logoutMenuOption:
            if (logoutAppPressAgain + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                logoutToast.cancel();

                removeAnonymousVendorUser();
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                removeAnonymousVendorUser();
                Intent logoutIntent = new Intent(VendorMapsActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(logoutIntent);
                finish();
            } else {
                logoutToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.press_button_again_to_logout, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                logoutToast.show();
            }

            logoutAppPressAgain = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
```

**Log out method when user presses back twice:**

```
        public void onBackPressed() {
    if (exitAppPressBack + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        exitAppBackToast.cancel();
        super.onBackPressed();

        removeAnonymousVendorUser();
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        Intent logoutIntent = new Intent(VendorMapsActivity.this, 
        WelcomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(logoutIntent);
        finish();
        } else {
        exitAppBackToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
        R.string.press_back_one_more_time_to_exit, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        exitAppBackToast.show();
        }

    exitAppPressBack = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

**This is the code that creates the users when they login anonymously:**

```
     public void sellAnonymously(View view) {

    circProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnSuccessListener(VendorLoginActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {

            Toast.makeText(VendorLoginActivity.this, "Success!  Enjoy the app!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String client_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            DatabaseReference client_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Vendor").child(client_id);
            client_db.setValue(true);
            circProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            // Sends anonymous user to VendorMapsActivity
            startActivity(new Intent(VendorLoginActivity.this, VendorMapsActivity.class));

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you step through `removeAnonymousVendorUser` in a debugger yet? Does `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` have a value? If so, is `client_id` the value you expect? If so, does `client_db.removeValue()` log any relevant (error) message?

Comment: I ran the debug to my physical device and put a stop on the `removeAnonymousVendorUser()` within my and it does run delete user.  I spent the last 4+ hours learning how to debug as I am new to the whole debug process, sorry I am still learning.  But I can confirm `removeAnonymousVendorUser()` works for both onBackPressed and Logout button logouts.  It is the onDestroy logout that is not removing the data.  It logs the user out, but does not delete their data.

Comment: Figured it out.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14024573/9842400 Everything now works.  I just needed to put the `removeAnonymousVendorUser()` before the `super.onDestroy();`  Thanks for your help friend and guidance in the right direction!

Comment: This is strange, `removeAnonymousVendorUser()` does not seem to remove the users data anymore from the database when used with `onDestroy()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To delete a user, call `user.delete()` as shown in the Firebase documentation on [deleting a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#delete_a_user):

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

user.delete()
```

---

To delete data from the database for the current user, call `removeValue()` on a reference to that data as shown in the Firebase documentation on [deleting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#delete_data):

```
ref.removeValue()
```

---

You can combine the two by using Cloud Functions for Firebase. In that case you respond to the user being deleted, by deleting their data from the database. For a short explanation of this, see the Firebase documentation on [triggering Cloud Functions when a user is deleted](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_deletion):

```
exports.deleteUserData = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {
  // ...
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I am going to try this out!

Comment: Awesome!  Got it to work!  It works with onBackPressed to log out and on case R.id.logoutMenuOption to log out.  Except, it seems to not work with `@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //TODO: Figure out how to delete UID and user when they sign out
        removeAnonymousVendorUser();
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        finish();
    }`  Nothing happens when I slide to close the app from the scroll.  The data is still in the Firebase Database and Firebase Auth.

Comment: I am using the `removeAnonymousVendorUser();
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();` in that order.  This is the code to the method `private void removeAnonymousVendorUser() {

        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {

            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            user.delete();
        }

        DatabaseReference vendorIdReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Vendor");
        vendorIdReference.removeValue();

    }`